# Iterating through a rails object

Tags: ruby

I have an error object e, with the following structure:

```
e.error_code
e.message
```

It, however, may have additional symbols, such as:

```
e.error_details
```

How do I iterate through the e object?

I tried

```
e.each do |error|
  ...
end
```

But I get an error message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<Smartsheet::ApiError: Too many sheets to copy.>)
```

This is a Smartsheet API error object. The code below works:

```
begin
    @smartsheet.workspaces.copy(workspace_id: workspace_id, body: {new_name: new_name}))
rescue Smartsheet::ApiError => e
  puts "Error Code: #{e.error_code}"
  puts "Message: #{e.message}"
end
```

end

Comment: can you share the error message

Comment: This entirely depends on the class of `e` and what methods it has. Can you share them?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: From your edit it seems like you're working with an [`Smartsheet::ApiError`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/smartsheet/2.86.1/Smartsheet/ApiError) instance. However your question isn't really clear to me. The `Smartsheet::ApiError` instance has a set amount of methods that you can use, what do you want to iterate? One thing I can imagine iterating is the `e.headers` since, that's an key/value-collection. You also mention *"But I get an error message"*, this doesn't really help. You should include the error message into the question to enable us to help you.

Comment: I edited it and added the error message

Comment: seems like no each method is defined on the ApiError class and it's parents. how ever you can iterate through the instance variables like the code I provided below

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
e.instance_variables.each do |error|
  ...
end
```

This will give you the attributes, if you want the value you could use

```
e.instance_variable_get(error)
```

inside the do clause